# Linking with OpenSSL fails with Heartbleed security advisory even after upgrading it

Tags: openssl, radius, heartbleed-bug

while running radius server in debugging mode by using the command **radiusd -X**, i got a problem like this

### the error is shown as below:

> Refusing to start with libssl version OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 (in range 1.0.1 - 1.0.1f).  Security advisory CVE-2014-0160 (Heartbleed)
>   For more information see http://heartbleed.com

### the installed openssl version is shown below:

> OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014

eventhough i installed/updated OpenSSL 1.0.1g, i got an error called heartbleed. i stucked in this problem ,could any one help me out of this???

Answer (score 0):

It's not picked up your installed version. You'll need to re-run configure and recompile (if building form source). Verify all other versions have been removed, or pass `--with-openssl-include-dir` `--with-openssl-lib-dir` to configure to specify explicit paths.

The debian packages for 3.0.4 already have patches which check for the correct debian packaged version, and alter the config files to ignore the check.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    cd /usr/local/etc/raddb
    vi radiusd.conf
```

Somwhere in the line no 480 odd in the security subsection,
You will find a line like this

```
    allow_vulnerable_openssl = no
```

Change it to

```
    allow_vulnerable_openssl = yes
```

Comment: helllo @Abhay ,the file **radiusd.conf** in the path of **/usr/local/etc/raddb** is shown as *binary file*  how would i change/modifie no to yes in the 480th line.

Comment: u mean radiusd.conf is a binary file
run "file usr/local/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf" and tell me the output

Comment: It's not a binary file

Comment: Once you have *verified* that the version of OpenSSL you're using has been patched you should set ``security`` ``allow_vulnerable_openssl`` to ``CVE-2014-0160`` as per the debug output.

You should *NOT* set it to yes.

Comment: @Arran: allow_vulnerable_openssl = yes worked for me
and it is mentioned in the official freeradius website here
http://freeradius.org/security.html

Comment: @AbhayChennagiri it may work, but it means you won't be notified of future vulnerabilities. I've fixed the webpage to add further clarification.